# Flutter - HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: node.js, flutter, apache, https

DISCLAIMER: I know that this question was asked before multiple times, non of the answers helped me.

In our app, we implemented SSL for more security, but we sometimes get the mentioned error, the error is not persistent, meaning that the same route can success at time but other time it throws this error.

Nothing is displayed on the server logs.

This is how I setup SSL configuration in the app:

```
(client.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = (HttpClient _client) {
  SecurityContext sc = SecurityContext();
  sc.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(sslCert.buffer.asInt8List());
  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(context: sc);
  httpClient.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => false;
  httpClient.maxConnectionsPerHost = 10;
  return httpClient;
};
```

client being a Dio instance

Our server is built using Node.js, with Apache on centOS